# Reactjs onSubmit is not working with form tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working on Reactjs and i am using nextjs framework,Right now i am trying to validate form using reactjs but i am not getting "alert" after click on submit button,How can i do this ? I tried with following code but not working

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import { Inter } from '@next/font/google'
import styles from '@/styles/Home.module.css'
const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export default function Home() {
 const { handleSubmit } = useForm();

const checkauth = (data:any) => {
 alert("Hello world");
};
 return (
   <div className="container">
     <div className="screen">
       <div className="screen__content">
         <form className="login" onSubmit={handleSubmit(checkauth)}>
           <div className="login__field">
             <i className="login__icon fas fa-user" />
             <input
               type="text"
               className="login__input"
               placeholder="User name / Email"
             />
           </div>
           <div className="login__field">
             <i className="login__icon fas fa-lock" />
             <input
               type="password"
               className="login__input"
               placeholder="Password"
             />
           </div>
           <button className="button login__submit">
             <span className="button__text">Log In Now</span>
             <i className="button__icon fas fa-chevron-right" />
           </button>
         </form>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 );
}
```

Comment: onSubmit={()=>handleSubmit(checkauth)}

Answer (score 0):

Try using event.preventDefault() in your checkAuth function.
Also button should have type=“submit”.

Comment: still not working,

Comment: still not working i used following code
const checkauth = (data:any,event:any) => {
  event.preventDefault();
 alert("Hello world");
};

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />

Comment: Did you use type=submit with button too?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to simulate this on react with `register` and it's working. Find code below -

```
import React from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

export default function TempForm() {
    const { handleSubmit, register } = useForm();

    const checkauth = (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        alert('Hello world');
    };

    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='screen'>
                <div className='screen__content'>
                    <form className='login' onSubmit={handleSubmit(checkauth)}>
                        <div className='login__field'>
                            <i className='login__icon fas fa-user' />
                            <input
                                type='text'
                                className='login__input'
                                placeholder='User name / Email'
                                {...register('username')}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className='login__field'>
                            <i className='login__icon fas fa-lock' />
                            <input
                                type='password'
                                className='login__input'
                                placeholder='Password'
                                {...register('password')}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <button className='button login__submit'>
                            <span className='button__text'>Log In Now</span>
                            <i className='button__icon fas fa-chevron-right' />
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```